# Html file upload to server

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am building a Cordova app and I want the user to upload it's profile image through a HTML form. If the form is like the example from W3C ( the example bellow) how the Php file must look like? I tried the example from W3C but it's not saving anything to the server. I use 000webhost as server.  Someone said that instead of using upload.php, I can just write there (at action=" ") the adress of the server and the folder, is that working?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Read about PHP file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: there is no php here

Answer (score -1):

Configure The "php.ini" File
First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

Comment: 000webhost does not let them have any control over editing that file.

Comment: While this may be necessary, this isn't a fully encompassing answer.  As the op has shown no php, which should be addressed before much else.

Comment: As Fred sayd,  I can't acces the php.ini file on 000webhost